# Program does not scan a text file (Java)

Tags: java, text

I was having trouble getting my program to read from a file "lexicon.txt" 
My task was to have the program scan a user input and getting the word count for the program in return. Do you guys know what's going on in my code?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class searchFile {
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the file name (e.g: nonamefile.txt)");
    String objective = reader.nextLine();

    if (!(objective.equals("lexicon.txt"))) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Missing File");
    }
    else {
        Scanner reader2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner lexicon = new Scanner(new File("lexicon.txt"));
        int wordCount = 0;
        System.out.println("What word do you need to look up?");
        String objective2 = reader2.nextLine();

        while (lexicon.hasNext()) {
            String word = lexicon.next();
            if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(objective2)){
                wordCount++;
            }                
        }
        System.out.println("Word count = " + wordCount);
    }
} // end main method (String Args[])
} // end class searchFile
```

Comment: Try adding `System.out.println(new File("lexicon.txt").exists());` and make sure it prints `true`...

Comment: Without seeing the file, it's difficult to know, but maybe `String word = lexicon.nextLine();` would be more useful...maybe not...

Comment: Yes, it prints true... and the nextLine() method doesn't change anything.

Comment: I thing you need to consume the nextline after printing `Please enter the file name (e.g: nonamefile.txt)`. Just change the `println` to `print` and then try

Comment: @Tirath The OP already does, that's what `nextLine` does...

Comment: Then we're going to need an example of the `lexicon.txt`...

Comment: lexicon.txt is a simple txt file that contains words copied and pasted from a source.

Comment: I copy pasted your source and its working fine for me. Are you passing file name properly like - `lexicon.txt` not `lixicon`?

Comment: I think so, the program executes every part. It just doesn't read the file and gives me a word count on the string I input.

Comment: @Destinox We get the wordcount only after the passed file is read. Isn't that what your program is supposed to do?

Comment: It had something to do with the text file and its contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code on my computer. It is to help you. may be you are not doing same.

```
Please enter the file name (e.g: nonamefile.txt)
lexicon.txt
What word do you need to look up?
three
Word count = 3
```

The text I used in `lexicon.txt` was that :

```
one
two two 
three three three
```

And it is working fine.
Remember, just copy paste is not like what you think it. there could be any character in *clipboard* when you copy that you cannot see, and pasting it also pastes these code too in your text file. 
`Scanner.next()` looks for the next string delimited by `word boundries`.
Suppose there is a text that you copy pasted :
[image]
which is not visible in notepad :
[image]
So when you will search for "Hello", it will not be there.
You will have to search for [image] instead, but you cannot write this easily.

Comment: Wow it works! so what's the difference between the copy and pasted code and the words we actually typed up?

Comment: I got it. Need to check the text contents. Many Thanks!